# Render Component Dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, dashboard, gridster

I have this array:

```
this.dashboard = [
     {name: '<app-incassi-provvigioni></app-incassi-provvigioni>'},
     {name: '<app-scheda-punti-vendita></app-scheda-punti-vendita>'}
]
```

I populate this array on the ngOnInit cycle.
I was wondering how can I render the components when I read my array in the html like that:

```
<gridster [options]="gridsterOptions">
    <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
        <!-- your content here -->
        {{item.name}}
    </gridster-item>
</gridster>
```

Of course right now it returns the string contained in the object but I'm trying to find a solution to render the component.
It is possible to do that?

More details:
I am developing a dashboard type app where I retrieve the list of the user dashlet from the DB and I'm trying to render those components dynamically once the main app component is ready.
using Angular 7 & Gridster2.

Comment: what about `<div [innerHTML]="item.name"></div>`....?

Comment: @Edison it creates an empty div inside the dashlet container. it's not rendering the component.

Comment: Angular has a very good guide on using dynamic components. I think you should refer this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: So all the string (`component-selectors`) are a part of the same module ?

Comment: why using tag ?! why you don't use CompnentClass as element in your array. this will make it easier in the component loader factory.

Answer (score 9):

You can inject component [dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Just create component with @Input() component;

```
export class DynamicContentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() component: any;
  @Input() data: any;

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();

    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<DynamicComponentRef>componentRef.instance).data = this.data;
  }
}
```

And use it in HTML

```
<app-dynamic-content [component]="someComponent" [data]="data"></app-dynamic-content>
```

Data example

```
someComponent = SchedaPuntiVendita;
```

Dynamic components should be added to `entryComponents` in your `module`

Also you can create some kind of `factory` which will receive some string and depends on it returns you component class

Factory example

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicContentComponentFactory {

  constructor() { }

  get(type: ContentType): any {
    switch (type) {
      case 'scheda':
        return SchedaPuntiVendita;
    }
  }
```

And modify `DynamicContentComponent` a little

```
@Input() contentType: string;

constructor(..., private factory: DynamicContentComponentFactory) { }
...

const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.factory.get(this.contentType));

...
```

Comment: The ComponentFactoryResolver is no longer needed. The Angular team has streamlined it so you can directly create the component like this: `this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.component);`

Answer (score 7):

rather passing component tag name("app-incassi-provvigioni" in your case), pass the component name (TestComponenet), then call the function from your view and render it as dynamically with Directive.

eg:

```
<gridster [options]="gridsterOptions">
  <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
    <div class="inner">
      <ng-template dynamic-template> </ng-template>
    </div>
  </gridster-item>
</gridster>
```

dynamic-template is a directive, that help us to load the component.

Comment: this sounds interesting, can you provide some code example please?

Comment: @LucaAlberto, i just did the sample code check the link: [link ] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz8w1u). please mark as answer if this is suite for you. thanks

Comment: Man, you just saved my day. This answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use an angular switch for this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="item.name">
    <app-incassi-provvigioni *ngSwitchCase="incassi"></app-incassi-provvigioni>
    <app-scheda-punti-vendita *ngSwitchCase="scheda"></app-scheda-punti-vendita>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gridster2, actually there is reference so you could use npm package as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component .

Here is an example of my code:

```
 <gridster-item
      class="gridster-item"
      [item]="item.gridItem"
      *ngFor="let item of dashboard; let i = index"
      (itemResize)="getItemSize($event, i)"
    >
      <button class="button-remove-item" (click)="removeItem(item)">
        <img src="assets/remove-item.svg" />
      </button>
      <div class="gridster-item-inner">
        <ndc-dynamic
          [ndcDynamicInputs]="item.size"
          [ndcDynamicComponent]="item.component.data"
        ></ndc-dynamic>
      </div>
    </gridster-item>
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.dashboard = [
         {name: 'dashboard1'},
         {name: 'dashboard2'}
    ]

    <gridster [options]="gridsterOptions">
        <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
            <ng-container *ngIf="item.name === 'dashboard1'" *ngTemplateOutlet="dashboard1">
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="item.name === 'dashboard1'" *ngTemplateOutlet="dashboard2">
            </ng-container>
        </gridster-item>
    </gridster>


    <ng-template #dashboard1>
        <app-incassi-provvigioni></app-incassi-provvigioni>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #dashboard2>
        <app-scheda-punti-vendita></app-scheda-punti-vendita>
    </ng-template>
```